# Pull data from SQL Server via URL in Python

Tags: python, xml, reporting-services

I am needing to pull data from a secure website via xml or atomsvc file with an embedded url. I am unable to access via python BS4 or requests because of authorization issues, yet without Python i can access the link and SQL database just fine. I simply want to pull all the data via the url, then save it to another file. Is that possible? Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

EDIT: 
This is what ive tried so far. It downloads a file, but it html of unauthorized access, yet when i go to the url without Python, i can access it.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import wget

root = ET.parse('Live Workload Report.atomsvc').getroot()

att = []
for i in root[0]:
    att.append(i.attrib)

href = att[1]['href']

filename = wget.download(href)
```

Comment: ssh into the server, fetch the data, scp it out.

Comment: try something and let us know when you get stuck

Comment: From the website they have a file that says data feed. Its an atomsvc file with xml inside. It has an href in the file thats linked to the SQL Server. If i click on the link, im able to access it, but if i use requests or BS4, it sends me to an unauthorized page. I would like to show you all, but im not sure if i would be disclosing secure information. Thanks

Comment: Can you 'curl' or 'wget' those hyperlinks?